# Sorting array with null values

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that allows user to delete an element from an array and I am trying to sort them in alphabetic order using compareTo(); through a for loop. However, the null values are giving me problems. For example an array with null values:

```
String[] myArray = {"Apple", "Banana", null, "Durian", null, null, "Grapes"};
```

When Java is comparing them and reads a null value, it would give me a NullPointerException.

Is there any way that I can sort this array with null values at the back? For example:

```
{"Apple", "Banana", "Durian", "Grapes", null, null, null}
```

I know that using Vectors can solve the problem but I am just curious if there is any way that I can just do it without changing my array to vectors.

Comment: With Guava, this is straightforward: `Arrays.sort(array, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())`

Answer (score 27):

try this

```
    Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (o1 == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (o2 == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }});
```

it produces the required order

Answer (score 7):

write your own `Comparator` that accepts null values, and pass that comparator to the `Arrays.sort(`) method