# How can I double the size of the array without getting NullPointException?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

First, for quick context, here's my post from yesterday:

[How to work around a NullPointerException in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675437/how-to-work-around-a-nullpointerexception-in-java)

So I'm getting this NullPointerException, which I now believe is occurring before I try to find the index of the first duplicate in the array of strings. Before I search for the index of the first duplicate, I double the size of the string array using this method:

```
static String[] upSizeArr( String[] fullArr )
{

    int size = fullArr.length; 
    String[] newSizeArr = new String[(2 * size)]; 
    for (int a = 0; a < size; a++) {
        newSizeArr[a] = fullArr[a];
    }
    return newSizeArr;
}
```

and I then use that method in the context of this while loop:

```
static final int CAPACITY = 10;
int wordCount = 0;

BufferedReader wordFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(args[1]) );
String[] wordList = new String[CAPACITY];

while ( wordFile.ready() ) 
    {   if ( wordCount == wordList.length ) 
            wordList = upSizeArr( wordList );
        wordList[wordCount++] = wordFile.readLine();
    } 
wordFile.close();
```

Is there any possible work around for this using the upSizeArr method? I would prefer the solution be basic and using only arrays with no other data structures. I am new to programming and am really trying to get a grasp of the fundamentals...been looking for a solution to this NullPointException for about a week or so now.

Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Practice
{
    static final int CAPACITY = 10;
    static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length < 1 )
        {
            System.out.println("\nusage: C:\\> java Practice <words filename>\n\n"); // i.e. C:\> java Lab2 10Kints.txt 172822words.txt
            System.exit(0);
        }


    String[] wordList = new String[CAPACITY];
    int wordCount = 0;
    BufferedReader wordFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(args[0]) );

    while ( wordFile.ready() ) // i.e. while there is another line (word) in the file
    {   if ( wordCount == wordList.length ) 
            wordList = upSizeArr( wordList );
        wordList[wordCount++] = wordFile.readLine();
    } //END WHILE wordFile
    wordFile.close(); 
    System.out.format( "%s loaded into word array. size=%d, count=%d\n",args[0],wordList.length,wordCount );
    int dupeIndex = indexOfFirstDupe( wordList, wordCount );
    if ( dupeIndex == NOT_FOUND )
        System.out.format("No duplicate values found in wordList\n");
    else
        System.out.format("First duplicate value in wordList found at index %d\n",dupeIndex);

} // END OF MAIN

// TWO METHODS 

static String[] upSizeArr( String[] fullArr )
{

    int size = fullArr.length; //find the length of the arrays
    String[] newSizeArr = new String[(2 * size)]; // creates new array, doubled in size
    for (int a = 0; a < size; a++) {
        newSizeArr[a] = fullArr[a];
    }
    return newSizeArr;

}
static int indexOfFirstDupe( String[] arr, int count )
{       
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    int size = arr.length;
    int index = NOT_FOUND;

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < size; y++) {
            if (arr[x].equals(arr[y])) {
                index = x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
    }
} // END OF PROGRAM
```

Also, the file that's being used as the argument is a txt file of strings.

Comment: I don't see anything the code you provided that would be dereferencing null. Can you provide more context/code? Where exactly is the exception thrown? In your original post that you linked to, the exception is due to half of the array (the "new" half after resizing) containing `null`s, which `Arrays.sort` will throw an exception attempting to compare `null`s. This can be resolved by creating a Comparator that handles `null`, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514467/sorting-array-with-null-values

Comment: I'd recommend `ArrayList` or [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int))

Comment: `wordFile.ready()` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Which line is actually throwing the exception?

Comment: So I did a really quick hack of your code, without trying to read a file, and it doesn't generate a NPE. I suspect the combination of `wordFile.ready()` and `wordList[wordCount++] = wordFile.readLine()` will put `null` values into the array (`wordFile.readLine()` will return `null` when it reaches the end of the file).

Comment: John, the exception is the same as it was in the last post, so I rewrote the Arrays.sort(arr) to Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())); and the program keeps continually running now without finishing. Am I missing another component? I know it pushes the nulls to the back of the array, but do I have to take it a step further?

Comment: Post the exception along with your stack trace so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's the cause of your problem, but it is very suspicious...

```
while ( wordFile.ready() ) {
    //...
}
```

is not how you should be reading the file.  Instead, you should be checking the return result of `readLine`, which will return `null` when it reaches the end of the file.

Maybe something more like....

```
try (BufferedReader wordFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[1]))) {
    String[] wordList = new String[CAPACITY];

    String text = null;
    while ((text = wordFile.readLine()) != null) {
        if (wordCount == wordList.length) {
            wordList = upSizeArr(wordList);
        }
        wordList[wordCount++] = text;
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your code also runs the risk of leaving the file resource open.  The above example makes use of the `try-with-resources` statement to ensure that it is closed properly, regardless of the success of the operation.

Take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details.

Unless it's a specific requirement, I would also recommend using an `ArrayList` or [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) over rolling your own solution like this.

Maybe have a look at [List Implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html) for some more details

## Update from runnable example...

After having a play without a runnable example of the code, when `upSizeArr` creates a new array, it's defaulting the new elements to `null`, which is expected, I'm surprised that `Arrays.sort` can't handle this.

"A" solution is to fill the unused space with a different non-default value...

```
static String[] upSizeArr(String[] fullArr) {

    int size = fullArr.length; //find the length of the arrays
    String[] newSizeArr = new String[(2 * size)]; // creates new array, doubled in size
    for (int a = 0; a < size; a++) {
        newSizeArr[a] = fullArr[a];
    }
    for (int a = size; a < newSizeArr.length; a++) {
        newSizeArr[a] = "";
    }
    return newSizeArr;

}
```

"Another" solution might be to "downsize" the array to fit the available data...

```
static String[] downsizeToCapacity(String[] fullArr) {
    int lastIndex = 0;
    while (lastIndex < fullArr.length && fullArr[lastIndex] != null) {
        lastIndex++;
    }
    if (lastIndex >= fullArr.length) {
        return fullArr;
    }
    String[] downSized = new String[lastIndex];
    System.arraycopy(fullArr, 0, downSized, 0, lastIndex);

    return downSized;
}
```

All this tries to do is create a new array whose size is only large enough to contain all the none-null values and return that.

You could then use to something like...

```
System.out.format("%s loaded into word array. size=%d, count=%d\n", "words.txt", wordList.length, wordCount);
wordList = downsizeToCapacity(wordList);
System.out.format("%s loaded into word array. size=%d, count=%d\n", "words.txt", wordList.length, wordCount);

int dupeIndex = indexOfFirstDupe(wordList, wordCount);
```

Which, in my testing, outputs

```
words.txt loaded into word array. size=160, count=99
words.txt loaded into word array. size=99, count=99
No duplicate values found in wordList
```

Comment: Hey, appreciate the help! Unfortunately the array is a specific requirement and I need to use Arrays.sort() as per the professor's request. Is there anyway I could rewrite the method instead of the while( wordFile() ), as that is code I am not allowed to modify? I was tasked with merely making the method. I tried putting Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())); to put the null values in the back of the array and the program just keeps running...am I making progress? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: *"the while( wordFile() ), as that is code I am not allowed to modify?"* ...  ... but that's the code that is wrong and is likely the source of your problem.  I've tested the array resizing and it seems to work fine for me, although I might use `arraycopy` instead

Comment: Ugh, sorry about that man! Is there anyway in which I can rewrite my methods so the code will at least run? I tried the arraycopy way too :( My professor is not looking for efficiency or elaborate code (as he himself seems to not have the most "efficient" code xD)

Comment: Put in checks for `null` values and default them to something not `null`

Comment: Okay, so both my upSizeArr method and my indexOfFirstDupe method in my original post look good? I tried: String[] cleanedArray = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new); to clean up the arr array but now my program won't finish running...

Comment: Don't know about `indexOfFirstDupe`, but the resizing seems to work.  I would look at `wordFile.readLine()`, if it returns `null`, then ignore the value ... or have another method which takes the results and removes `null` values

Comment: So I tried:
String[] cleanedArray = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(Objects::nonNull).toArray(String[]::new); to clean up the arr array but now my program won't finish running...

Comment: Okay, it's probably time you provided a [complete, runnable example]9(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, including the data you're using

Comment: See my original post above with the edited full code!